# Linqpad throwing DumpExtensions exception

Tags: linqpad

I have the linqpad premium edition.

When performing a simple query such as:

```
var x = MyContext.Where (o => o.Id == 1);
x.Dump();
```

I'm getting an error saying

> The type initializer for 'DumpExtensions' threw an exception.

Here is a screen shot of the InnerException.
[image]

I've searched on the LinqPad site and posted a question on their forum but can't find a solution to the issue. *This exception didn't start until I purchased the premium edition and put in the activation code.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are (directly or indirectly) referencing an assembly that defines a class called `DumpExtensions` with an extension method called `Dump`. If it's more specific than LINQPad's `Dump` method, it will get called instead of LINQPad's extension method.

Given that you have a premium license, the easiest way to diagnose this is to put the cursor on `Dump` and hit F12 (go to definition). This will launch ILSpy and take you to the definition.

Comment: that was it. I had installed a 'dump extension' from nuget into my solution. i uninstalled it and linqpad dump works now. Thanks